# How to install an erlang package system wide instead of as a dependency?

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I am trying to set up couchdb for development locally. Was going through the troubleshooting page http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/troubleshooting.html and it had some instructions to check a few deps that were needed to set it up correctly.

Like `crypto:md5_init().` and `snappy:compress("gogogogogogogogogogogogogogo").`  which are not there on my machine locally, my question is that how do I install these packages using a package management tool like rebar3 something like `rebar3 install` to just have the library on my machine, instead of adding it to a config file as a dep and running rebar.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For use `crypto`, you need install `erlang-crypto` in your computer:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install erlang-crypto
```

Then for run/stop `crypto` in Erlang shell:

```erlang
1> crypto:start().
ok
2> crypto:stop().
=INFO REPORT==== dd-mmm-yyyy::hh:mm:ss.mmmmm ===
    application: crypto
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary
```

Comment: thanks, will I have to follow this procedure for other libraries like snappy too? find their apt repos and install them?

Comment: Not sure, I suppose you will need also install `erlang-tools`, then need to take a look what exactly functionality you still needed. Sometime you can add to project some library as dependencies use `rebar` etc.